# where to close the scanner used more then once in the class

Tags: java, methods, input, java.util.scanner

As i know its better practice to have as less code duplication as possible, So i decided to declare only one scanner throughout the class, but where shall I close the scanner object or is it not necessarily to close it, what does closing the scanner do.

```
  private Scanner scanner;
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Scanner
 */
public Ssss()
{
    // initialise instance variables
     scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}
public void enterYourName()
{
    System.out.println("Enter your Name");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your name is:" + name);
}
public void enterYourAge()
{
    System.out.println("Enter your Age");
    int age = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your age is: " + age);
}
```

Comment: Where do you call your `enterYour***` methods? (Please provide some code for where you call those methods). When the inputs are done, the scanner should be closed.

Comment: i dont really call them because i am using bluej we do this manually

Comment: This is an excellent question and uncovers some subtle and deep principles of OO design: encapsulation and composition, and putting responsibility where it belongs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this code is in a class `Ssss` (as it appears), consider:

1. Your class contains and uses a `Scanner` object, so it is responsible for closing it.
2. The `Scanner` represents an internal resource, *and* state of your class... different methods will refer to it at different times.
3. You cannot know when the user of your class (the main program?) is done with it, so you cannot unilaterally close the `Scanner` -- where would you close it?

The solution is that your class `Ssss` must provide its own method that allows the code using `Ssss` to say "I'm done with you".  This method is traditionally called `close()`, and in it you would close the Scanner (and clean up any other resources).

The client (calling class) must wrap usage of your class `Ssss` in a try-finally block and call *your* `close()` method in the `finally` clause.

If you are using Java7, your class `Ssss` should implement `AutoCloseable` so it can be used in a try-with-resources statement to take advantage of that Java7 feature.